# More than one preg_match queries?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am a newbie to php and trying to write the code that validates my form.now the problem is I am having trouble in this line of code:

```
$fullname_pattern = "/[a-zA-Z]+/";
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$email_pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?@[a-zA-Z]{3,50}\.(com|net|org)/";

$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_pattern = "/(.){6,12}/";


if(preg_match($fullname_pattern,$fullname)) && 
      (preg_match($email_pattern,$email)) && 
      (preg_match($password_pattern,$password)) 
        {             
            header("Location: home.php");
        }
     else
            header("Location: registration.php");
```

Don't know what to do!

Comment: And the trouble is?

Comment: Check where your `)` are, there's an issue.

Comment: The trouble is a parse error

Comment: Don't use regex to validate the email. Use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(preg_match($fullname_pattern,$fullname))`
Remove Last ")"

And add here `(preg_match($password_pattern,$password)))`

Like this:

`if(preg_match($fullname_pattern,$fullname)
   && preg_match($email_pattern,$email)
   && preg_match($password_pattern,$password)
) {`

Comment: It works! Thank you.